# How to run Python module with PM2 ecosystem file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pm2

I can run a Python script with PM2 with the following ecosystem file:

```json
{
    "apps": [{
        "name": "my_app",
        "script": "script.py",
        "instances": "1",
        "wait_ready": true,
        "autorestart": false,
        "interpreter" : "/home/my_user/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/my_app-ij6Dv2sY-py3.10/bin/python",
    }]
}
```

That works fine but i have another program that i can only start this way:

```bash
python -m my_app
```

But for this i can not simply change the ecosystem file to this:

```json
{
    "apps": [{
        "name": "my_app",
        "script": "-m my_app",
        "instances": "1",
        "wait_ready": true,
        "autorestart": false,
        "interpreter" : "/home/my_user/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/my_app-ij6Dv2sY-py3.10/bin/python",
    }]
}
```

PM2 will run it without errors but my app will not be running. How can i use `-m my_app` with a PM2 ecosystem file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the args field in your file to pass the module name. like that:

```
{
    "apps": [{
        "name": "my_app",
        "script": "run_module.py",
        "args": "my_app",
        "instances": "1",
        "wait_ready": true,
        "autorestart": false,
        "interpreter" : "/home/my_user/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/my_app-ij6Dv2sY-py3.10/bin/python",
    }]
}
```

then you create a python file run_module.py in the same folder and it will work:

```
import runpy
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    module_name = sys.argv[1]
    runpy.run_module(module_name, run_name="__main__")
```

Comment: It doesn't throw an error but doesn't run my app. But still thanks for the idea. I will play around with it.

Comment: I couldn't provide the module name as an argument but if i add it directly into `run_module.py` then it works

Comment: It is likely due to the way PM2 passes arguments to the script. It is less error prone to hard coded it directly into the code like you just did.